# Why structure and its typedef consume different size when aligned?

Tags: c, alignment, size, structure, typedef

I was expecting both sizes are 8 but i get `sizeof(myStruct) = 16, sizeof(myType) = 8`. I compiled this on Windows 64-bit machine with MinGW.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct s1{
    int8_t a;
    int32_t b; 
} __attribute__((aligned));

typedef struct{
    int8_t a;
    int32_t b;
}s2 __attribute__((aligned));

struct s1 myStruct;
s2 myType;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("sizeof(myStruct) = %zu, sizeof(myType) = %zu\n", sizeof(myStruct), sizeof(myType));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've put `__attribute__((aligned))` after `s2`, instead of before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct s1 { … } __attribute__((aligned));` says the members of `struct s1` should be aligned to the “maximum alignment” for the target, which is apparently 8 bytes. So each member is put at a multiple of 8 bytes, making the whole structure 16 bytes. (The GCC [documentation on this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) fails to state that specifying this attribute for the structure affects its members, but that appears to be the case.)

`typedef struct { … } s2 __attribute__((aligned));` says `s2` is a structure with ordinary alignment requirements, so its `b` member is put at a multiple of 4 bytes and the total size is 8 bytes, and then the `s2` type should be aligned to the “maximum alignment”. Thus, when `s2` objects are created, they will be put at locations that are multiples of 8, but the layout of members within them will not change.

To make the `structure` defined with the `typedef` have the same layout as `struct s1`, you can use `typedef struct { … } __attribute__((aligned)) s2;`.